# vb.net - How to get the day number from a weekday name

Tags: vb.net, date, dayofweek, weekday

### Long story short:

I need the inverted function of `WeekdayName()`, in the following terms:

1. You provide a week day **name** (e.g. Sunday)
2. You get the correspondent week day **number** (that depends which is the first week day as returned in `WeekdayName`, e.g., you get 1 for Sunday if Sunday is the first day of the week)

### Background:

I'm using date functions in vb.net. So far so good. I'm using the function [`WeekdayName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8dc1aee%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in order to set the titles for tab pages in a `TabControl`. My custom control (kind of calendar control) holds the mentioned `TabControl` and it has the option of choosing which day of the week you want to diplay.

If you want to display ALL days, the `TabControl` will have `TabPage`s filled by iterating upon the `WeekdayName()` function mentioned above (localized and managed by the system calendar and capitalized by me).

If you set only Tuesday and Friday, you will have two tab pages with those titles and sorted as `[Tuesday | Friday]`. If you decide to add Wednesday, now you should have 3 tab pages: `[Tuesday | Wednesday | Friday]`, and so on...

In order to keep tabs sorted, when I need to insert a tab to be shown I want to provide the tab's title to check against the new-to-insert weekday name and in that way have the order resolved.

I believe one workaround is to create a fake date object with the tab's title string in it in order to have a, for instance, "Sunday" date and then use: [`Weekday()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82yfs2zh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) but I was hoping an API solution.

**NOTE:** This is **not**: *how to get the day number from a date*.

---

**EDIT:**

As we disscused with @jmshapland, a custom code approach using the default localization and system settings could be:

```
Function WeekdayNumber(day as String)
    ' The following initialization does not necessary go in this function.
    ' The idea is to have a mapping between key day name and index in the
    ' same order as the WeekdayName() method with the default system settings
    Dim weekdayNamesCollection as Collection = New Collection()
    For i = 1 to WEEKDAYS
        Dim wDay as String = WeekdayName(i)
        ' add the day with a key with the same name
        weekdayNamesCollection.add(wDay, wDay)
    Next i

    If weekdayNamesCollection.ContainsKey(day) Then
        Return weekdayNamesCollection.IndexOfKey(day) + 1
    End If

    ' Raise an error as the string 'day' is not in the collection
End Sub
```

I didn't test this out as I am in a computer without any framework and/or IDE. But basically, the idea is to return the index where the weekday name is stored in the collection (previously, it was stored in the system settings order as `WeekdayName()`.

Comment: Do you just want a basic look-up, for example if the user inputs Sunday return 1, Monday return 2, etc.. that is static where Sunday always equals 1?

Comment: No, I want this to be dependent of regional settings (as the `WeekdayName()` functions is, that returns "Sunday" when input was 1 and indeed Sunday is the first day of week). If it happens to choose Tuesday as the first day of week, then `WeekdayName()` will return "Tuesday" when 1 was the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a built-in function for it. But if you are using WeekdayName then you should use it for your purpose.

```
Public Function WeekDayNumber(ByVal weekName As String) As Integer

    Dim weekNames As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)

    For i As Integer = 1 To 7
        weekNames.Add(WeekdayName(i), i)
    Next

    Return weekNames(weekName)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this is formatted poorly, I never work with VB usually just C#. However, this should do what you are looking for... If you want the first day of the week to return as 0 instead of 1 just remove the + 1 from the return statement.

```
Private Function FindDayOfWeek(day As String) As Integer
    Dim daysOfWeek = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames

    Dim counter As Integer = Array.IndexOf(daysOfWeek, WeekdayName(1))
    Dim numericDay As Integer

    For i As Integer = 0 To 6
        If counter > 6 Then
            counter = 0
        End If

        If daysOfWeek(counter) = day Then
            numericDay = i
            Exit For
        End If
        counter += 1
    Next

    Return numericDay + 1
End Function
```

Comment: I appreciate your concern, however this approach does not support different locales and as I mentioned, I was hoping to find an API method. I could write a similar approach but I honestly believe always is better to use the appropriate framework method If any. Regards

Comment: The above edit should do the trick regardless of the culture the system that is running this is set to.

Answer (score 0):

By using `val()` function, will give Day of Week number from 0 to 6 :

`intDayofWeek = val(System.DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek)`